# Directive not loaded after Angular bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-bootstrap

From numerous blogs I've read that, when angular get's bootstrapped, all controllers / directives should be registered to a $compileProvider instance during the configuration phase, before they get applied.

I have tried this approach and cannot get this to work, take into account that I am using TypeScript 1.8 and AngularJS 1.5.

For the app.ts, I do a basic implementation and then bootstrap angular onto the document:

app.ts:

```
module playground.core
{
    "use strict";

    export let app: ng.IModule = angular.module("MyApp", []);   
    export let provider: ng.ICompileProvider = null;

    app.config(($compileProvider: ng.ICompileProvider): void =>
    {
        console.info("config hit");
        provider = $compileProvider;
    });

    angular.bootstrap(document, ["MyApp"]); 
}
```

At this point, the config(...) gets hit, and the provider instance is set correctly to the $compileProvider I inject into the config(...), as per Angular's documentation.

I then have a directive, called my-directive, which should simply show a bolded text on the page:

mydirective.ts:

```
module playground.directives
{
    "use strict";

    let load = (): void =>
    {
        if (playground.core && playground.core.provider)
        {   
            core.provider.directive.apply(null, ["myDirective", ["$compile", ($compile: ng.ICompileService): ng.IDirective =>
            {
                return <ng.IDirective>{
                    template: "<strong>Bold</strong>"
                };
            }]]);           
        }
        else
        {
            setTimeout(load);
        }
    };

    load();
}
```

I have a setTimeout, because, at the time of hitting the mydirective.ts file, the configuration has not been concluded yet, so provider will be null. Once this has been completed, does it successfully register the call, but the RETURN statement never fires.

I have tried numerous permutations of this approach (has to be TypeScript) and I cannot get it to work. If I change the line from **core.provider.directive.apply(...)** to **core.app.directive.apply(...)** it works?

I am completely stumped on this one.

Comment: have you checked the compiled javascript code?  how does it look?

Comment: I think you need to import app from core to the other modules to make this work.

Comment: or keep app global

Comment: compiled code is all good, core.app and core.provider is global (export let), there are no other modules, just the basic bootstrap and the directive as per the above. it works on app.directive, but not provider.directive.